# getRow() and getLastCellNum() of POI API

Tags: java, excel, class, methods, apache-poi

I am working with Excel (xlsx) in Java. I never understood the return value type 
from `getRow(int RowNum)`. What do you mean by "IT RETURNS THE LOGICAL ROW (0-Based)"? See below code.

```
row=sheet.getRow(0);
```

I am trying to get the data from 3rd row, 1st col. Apparently it worked and I got the
result what I need (only after writing bit of further code).

But, my question is how user manage to get data from 3rd row? when the rownum is
given as 0 (as you can see). I am expecting that it will (row) stick to 0th row ie. first row in Excel sheet.

`getLastCellNum()` method of XSSFRow class - what do you mean by "Gets the index of the last cell contained in this row PLUS ONE"?.

Comment: To get cell in the 3rd row and 1st column write `sheet.getRow(2).getCell(0)`. I can't see problem here. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

For `getRow(int RowNum)`, I think the logical row means it is a logical view on the physical sheet, but if you change the physical rows it will not get updated accordingly.

For example:

```
Row a = sheet.getRow(5);
Row b = sheet.createRow(0); // every physical row gets shifted down
System.out.println(a.getRowNum()); // still prints 5, logical row has not been updated
```

Concerning `getLastCellNum()`, I think it just means it returns the number of cells in the row (including blank ones). It just happens that the underlying datamodel stores this value and it is returned as-is, and it is also convenient for iterating on cells…

Comment: i need to go on trial error to see depth of getRow() and few other methods of poi API. Thanks for help.